# Run a String through Java using Pig

Tags: java, apache-pig

I have a UDF jar which takes in a String as an input through Pig. This java file works through pig fine as running a 'hard coded' string such as this command

```
B = foreach f generate URL_UDF.mathUDF('stack.overflow');
```

Will give me the output I expect

My question is I am trying to get information from a text file and use my UDF with it. I load a file and want to pass data within that file which I have loaded to the UDF.

```
LoadData = load 'data.csv' using PigStorage(',');
f = foreach LoadData generate $0 as col0, $1 as chararray
```

$1 is the column I needed and researching data types (http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#Data+Types) a char array is used.

I then tryed using the following command 
  B = foreach f generate URL_UDF.mathUDF($1);

to pass the data into the jar which fails stating

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.pig.data.DataByteArray cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

If anybody has any solution to this that would be great.

The java code I am running is as follows

```
package URL_UDF;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.pig.FilterFunc;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;
import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
import org.apache.pig.PigWarning;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.*;

public class mathUDF extends EvalFunc<String> {

public String exec(Tuple arg0) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{

        String urlToCheck = (String) arg0.get(0);

        return urlToCheck;
    }catch (Exception e) {
        // Throwing an exception will cause the task to fail.
        throw new IOException("Something bad happened!", e);
    }
}

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify the schema with LOAD as follows

```
LoadData = load 'data.csv' using PigStorage(',') AS (col0: chararray, col1:chararray);
```

and pass `col1` to the UDF.

Or

```
B = foreach LoadData generate (chararray)$1 AS col1:chararray;
```

Actually, this is a bug ([PIG-2315](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-2315)) in Pig which will be fixed in 0.12.1. The AS clause in foreach does not work as one would expect.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunatly this is still causing it to fail.

Comment: Then it's probably an error in your UDF. Could you post the code?

Comment: Added above this is a simple example I am currently running. I know it does nothing but even this still fails.

Comment: please do `describe f`

Comment: grunt> f = foreach LoadData generate $4 as col4:chararray;
grunt> describe f
f: {col4: chararray}

Comment: If you specify the schema when LOADing the data, it should work.

Comment: @user2931635 You should also try an explicit cast like `f = foreach LoadData generate (chararray) $4 as col4:chararray`.

Comment: @user2931635 I had a good feeling that was the problem. Fred, could you add [this link, to the bug,](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-2315) to your answer and give a brief explanation?